# Mandarin version of 冇屈得就屈 (Don't accuse me without evidence)?

Tags: cantonese

In Cantonese a common saying is 冇屈得就屈, which roughly translates to, "Don't accuse/frame me without evidence." (Literal: not able to frame then frame.)

It's used in contexts where A accuses B without much, or any, evidence.

What's the Mandarin version of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'冇屈得就屈; is short for '唔好屈得就屈' which means 'Don't frame me (accuse without evidence) just because you can'

Word to word transfers to Mandarin would be "別能冤枉就去冤枉" , However, in practice, '唔好屈得就屈' is  close to '不要隨便冤枉好人'  in Mandarin